# Free Duplicate mp3 finder

Tags: mp3, deduplication

Sometime back I had used a duplicate file finder for mp3 by analyzing the content.Unfortunately it was not free and the shareware had a lot of limitations.

Are there any freeware/OSS ones to detect and delete duplicate songs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try [MediaMonkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/). If you read [this thread](http://lifehacker.com/250629/ask-the-readers-find-and-remove-duplicate-mp3s#comments) on Lifehacker it comes highly recommended. It has scripts for identifying duplicates by metadata and hash values. The free version of MediaMonkey does all you need.

The advantage of using MediaMonkey is that you can do a whole lot more with it. You can add metadata info to your music, find and add album art (it looks great when you have your entire music library like that), automatically rename files based on metadata. It's an incredibly powerful organization app; in my mind, nothing comes close (believe me, I've tried a lot of stuff).

Comment: Why would you want to sue MediaMonkey?

Answer (score 3):

I love this program.

It's a **free** utility called [Fast Duplicate File Finder](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder/Fast-Duplicate-File-Finder-About.htm). It finds duplicate files in a folder and all its sub folders by analysing the data. The internal preview supports images, videos, music, text and binary files. That will help you find duplicate duplicate songs. That may be all you need.

But if your duplicate music is **in a different format**, this program (by the same company): [Audio Dedupe](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Duplicate-MP3-Finder/Audio-Dedupe-About.htm) will "listen" to your music so it can recognize a song even if it is saved in different file formats. Audio Dedupe is not free, but their free Duplicate File Finder may work for you.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Fairly old program but with many awesome features is [The Godfather](http://www.jtclipper.eu/thegodfather/). I have used it for years and it including Duplicate File Checking, batch Tag renaming and updating, automatic folder restructuring and many other useful features. It's also free and works on Windows 7/Vista/XP.

[image: Duplicate Finder]

Answer (score 0):

Should also look at [Auslogics Duplicate File Finder](http://www.auslogics.com/en/software/duplicate-file-finder). In addition to other criteria, it also does matching by content usind MD5 hash.
See this article describing how to use it : ["Trash All Your Duplicate Files with Auslogics Duplicate File Finder"](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/trash-all-your-duplicate-files-with-auslogics-duplicate-file-finder/).

Answer (score -1):

Any checksum tool would do fine to locate duplicate files normally.
But, with media files, a slight processing (or tag edit) changes the checksum,
rendering hash based comparisons useless.

Depending on the state of your copies, you could identify duplicates based on,

1. filenames

   - tags
   - checksum / [hashes](https://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder/8224#8224) (md5sum)

There are various answers here already that support these checks.
What matters is, the kind of duplicates you have.

Comment: Hmmm, a down vote without any description. Anything wrong in this answer? and do you value the fact that two media files with slight modifications could be difficult to match?

Comment: @nik: I've been downvoted too. I wonder if there's a way to find out the downvoter, because I believe it's systematic with this guy.

Comment: @harrymc, if its systematic, the site scripts will locate it and unroll the actions. I though someone forgot to note their downvote reason.

Comment: @harrymc, And voter identify is purposely hidden (http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/12984/is-there-a-way-to-see-who-both-up-down-voted-your-answer-question) only if they comment can it be guessed (or confirmed if they choose to prefix +1/-1). We expect responsible people to leave behind comments describing their downvotes.