# Finding duplicate music files

Tags: music, duplicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Free Duplicate mp3 finder](https://superuser.com/questions/37511/free-duplicate-mp3-finder)

Whats the best app, preferably free which will find duplicate songs on your hard disk?

If it would work even if they are of a different format that would be brilliant

Edit

I'm using windows 7

Comment: Mate, it would be lovely if you could name your OS.

Comment: Any particular naming scheme?  Or are you looking for "a.mp3 is the same as b.m4a, and they're both 'A Boy Named Sue'"?

Comment: Any Naming Scheme really

Answer (score 4):

[Media Monkey](http://www.mediamonkey.com/) is good at this and a bunch of other stuff.

Comment: +1 Highly recommended. I've had the best experiences with Media Monkey, and it's very good for managing even very large collections. You'll find it can do much more to help you sort and edit your library.

Comment: Used this years ago and was alright, its on its way down now

Comment: Media Monkey crashes while loading!

Comment: Crashed on x64 Win7 Have to run it in compatability mode :-(

Comment: +1 on the MediaMonkey suggestion, also I recommend these plug-ins:

 Advanced Duplicate Find & Fix
  http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=13000&sid=45fde5a54425a5896c2f2613a150c3f1

and 
  Tagging Inconsistencies 

http://www.mediamonkey.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=14734&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a

Comment: Runs absultely fine on my Windows 7 Professional RTM 64-bit install. I've got 3.1.2.1267 installed

Answer (score 0):

Fix tunes is good.
http://fixtunes.com

Or you could write your own program :)

Comment: looks rather iTunes-specific.  but it's redirecting to "TidySongs" so maybe you were trying to link to an actual FixTunes program?

Comment: The fixtunes site is now dead and the application is only downloadable from CNET: http://download.cnet.com/FixTunes/3000-2141_4-10280594.html

Answer (score 0):

iTunes has an option to show all duplicates based on same artist and song name, taken from the ID3 tags.  Not only that but you get a really nice media player as well. :)

Comment: God I hate ITunes with a passion! :-)

Comment: Guess I won't be getting a vote from you then ;)  I personally like iTunes (although it is the only Apple thing that I use), and I can't stand windows media player.

Comment: Winamp, with all its warts, is better than both.  Hey, care to start a religious war in the comments for this answer?  ;-)