# Software utitity to remove duplicate files

Tags: windows, software-rec, duplicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate file finder](https://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder)

How to I delete multiple copies of a same file from my hard drive?

Comment: This question has been asked before. Please take a look here: http://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder

Answer (score 0):

use [Duplicate File Finder](http://www.snapfiles.com/get/dupfilefinder.html) tools

and if you are looking for more tools look [here](http://www.raymond.cc/blog/archives/2007/12/17/find-and-remove-duplicate-files-to-free-up-hard-disk-space/)