# Application that locates redundant files on hdd

Tags: windows-7, hard-drive, windows-search, file-search

Is there an application that locates redundant files on the hard drive?  Files that are not crucial for the system to run. I'm running Windows 7.

Comment: Redundant isn't the same as non-crucial to the system. http://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder

Comment: *If* Windows 7 understands (and uses) hard links (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hard_link), then it might be hard to tell if the "redundant" file is actually using additional disk space?

Answer (score 1):

I really like [Clonespy](http://www.clonespy.com/).

It's free, and it's stable enough to handle scanning millions (10,000,000+) of files (I've actually managed to crash several other similar pieces of software ([noclone](http://noclone.net/))).

On the downside, it's a bit complex at first, but it's quite capable once you've used it a bit.

Answer (score 0):

finally found the answer, fyi this is what I was looking for: http://dll.nu/duper/