# App to delete doubles files? (dupes)

Tags: windows, duplicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate file finder](https://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder)

What app can i use to search a folder and remove doubles, triples, etc of a file? I know of noclone but i need to pay for that. Is there a freeapp i can use?

Comment: Anyone else find it ironic that a question about duplications was closed as a duplicate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I really like [Duplicate Cleaner](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/duplicate-cleaner) as recommended on [gizmo's freeware](http://www.techsupportalert.com/best-free-duplicate-file-detector.htm#dupcleaner)

Answer (score 0):

[Advanced system care free](http://www.iobit.com/advancedwindowscareper.html) comes with an Clone Files Finder with the program.  I use it, and it works fine.

Comment: Does it just list them and do I have to select **all** the dupes to delete them? Since this doesn't scale well if you need to delete thousands of files...

Comment: You are able to select and delete files within the program.

Comment: BTW @KronoS I recommend you add this answer to the original question, since I didn't see it listed