# Find duplicate images?

Tags: windows, images, duplicate

I need a software (for Windows) that finds duplicate images by comparing the actual image content. I have duplicates of images, once with metadata, one without, so the image is the same, but the file is not, so comparing the files byte by byte is not enough.

Another requirement is, that I can delete all / several duplicates at once - I don't want to click 100 times "delete"! That is, what I actually would have to do using XnView ): I also checked the other topics here and Google, but if a programscompares the images in a perfect way (like XnView) it doesn't allow the deletion of several duplicates at once

Comment: Check out the answers in this community wiki http://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder 

Might Help.

Answer (score 3):

Picasa 3 ([download link](http://picasa.google.com/)) has an experimental feature called "Show duplicate files". It will let you select multiples (CTRL + click, or drag to select) then DELETE them all. However, this is experimental. Some people report it working quite well.

The danger is always that you might delete the wrong photos. The reason software as you describe is hard to find is that no one wants to own the software responsible for deleting half of a user's photos when "they did nothing but now they're gone." :)

I found a source of good info on the feature here: [Picasa Tip: Finding Duplicate Pictures](http://picasatutorials.com/2010/01/picasa-tip-finding-duplicate-pictures/)

I would just note that "backup" is the word of the day for the adventure you are proposing. Good luck!

Answer (score 3):

I checked Google Picasa 3.8.0. It has a function to search for duplicates, but if two image files with the same picture have different metadata (and different size), Picasa don't recognize them as duplicates. You are out of luck here :)

Edit: In addition, if the image is re-sized, Picasa does not consider it a duplicate (this is an extension of having different metadata)

Comment: Actually when I choose show duplicate files, nothing happens? I am looking for images that are really identical, they are not resized, but on some of them the metadata was removed.

Comment: Yes, I understood that. I wanted to let you know that, unfortunately, Picasa 3.8.0 is no help in this case.