# Can any of the diff/grep utilities do a "file grep"?

Tags: windows-xp, grep, diff

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Duplicate file finder](https://superuser.com/questions/8223/duplicate-file-finder)

... to continue on the title, basically what I want is for me to give him the file, and the program goes through the whole project directory and seeks are there any files (they all differ in names, naturally :) that are binary same to the first one ...

It is in a way, diff, but I don't want to go through the project directory myself, since there are quite a lot of them.

Comment: I suppose you could script some quick checksum based thing... or a duplicate file finding software... OS?

Comment: @Paul - No, not the same as the question linked to. My files are of different names, and were you to cross-reference them by size, many ofther non-duplicate files would be included as well (they're all around 50-100kB).

Comment: @Paul - When I object to a duplicate-close, I don't observe every answer given in that question. I looked at the question, since your reason for closing was a "duplicate question", and dismissed it. Otherwise, we might start closing different questions that have mutual answers as well as duplicates.

Comment: This commentary is serving no purpose so I have deleted mine.  The question has been raised at meta http://meta.superuser.com/questions/3771/duplicate-question-where-the-answer-is-the-same-but-the-question-differs-sligh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>Sorry, didn't see the OS tag before posting. But would work on Windows with Cygwin or UnxUtils as well.</sub>

The following command computes the MD5 checksums for all files in the project directory and displays those with the same checksum as a reference file:

> `find /path/to/project -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | grep $( md5sum /path/to/reference/file | cut -c1-32 ) | cut -c35-`

The `cut` commands are used to extract the 32 character checksum (`-c1-32`) and the file name `(-c35-`) from the output of `md5sum`.

Comment: I have some port of UnxUtils for windows, I'll try this approach. Thanks!

Comment: @ldigas UnxUtils *is* the port. Good luck! If you don't have a bash or similar shell, call `md5sum /path/to/reference/file` separately and use the returned checksum as argument to `grep`.

Comment: No, it is a port of UnxUtils (so they say). It's called UnitKitTiny ... don't know where I got it from though.

Comment: @ldigas Nice, didn't know about that one. UnixKitTiny though. Will have to check it out.

Comment: [Here's a working link to download it](http://ipsec.pl/node/970).

Answer (score 0):

This works on Ubuntu 11.10:

```
#!/bin/bash
IFS="
"
for file in $(find $2 -type f)
do
    diff -s "$1" "$file" | grep "identical$"
done
```

It should work on any distro with `bash`, `find` and `diff`.

```
$ ./recursive_diff.sh 2.gif Pictures/
Files 2.gif and Pictures/qzhm4k.gif are identical
```

Comment: Sorry, forgot to add that. Windows XP here.