# Find Duplicate Folders in all partitions and or network partitions on my computer

Tags: windows, networking, duplicate

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which duplicate files and folders finders exist for Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/8223/which-duplicate-files-and-folders-finders-exist-for-windows)

I need a software to find large folder duplicates on my computer which match folder sizes exactly. It should be able to access multiple locations, and if possible network drives too.

I have tried duplicate file finder and it gives me thousand's of irrelevant entries, I want to find the largest folders. I have multiple instances as I am backing up data and have copied it all over for convenience.

Comment: Unless you can describe a specific situation that is not solved by conventional duplicate finder software, this is not a question that should be asked on SU. We don't do software recommendations here.

Answer (score 1):

[DiskView](http://www.diskview.com/screenshots.htm) (paid) would show the sizes of your folders and represent the space-hungry ones in a pie chart. I guess you could then easily infer (based on the given size/name) if you have duplicated folders.

It seems [Folder-size](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size-Screenshots.htm) (freeware) would do a bit more in addition as according to their [wesite](http://www.mindgems.com/products/Folder-Size/Folder-Size.html) it can sort folders according to:

```
Name
Folder size
Size percentage from the parent folders size
Files count inside the folder
Subfolders count
Creation time
Last modification time
Last access time Folder owner and group
```

Comment: These features do not remotely help the user identify duplicated folder trees. https://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/dcdownloads.html does this though, and is apparently the only one.